# Show a sequence of densities converge to some density.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence of density functions $f_{n}(x)$ and another density function $g(x)$, I was wondering to show 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f_{n}(x)-g(x)|dx=0,$$
is it enough to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=g(x)$? It seems that
$$|f_{n}(x)-g(x)|<f_{n}(x)+g(x)$$
and for any $n$
$$\int f_{n}(x)+g(x)dx=2,$$
so dominated convergence theorem applies?

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem requires that your dominating function does not depend on $n$. In general, Scheffe’s lemma tells that we need some form of ‘no mass escapes’ condition. In the case where you know that $f_n \to g$ a.e., this convergence upgrades to $L^1$ if and only if $\int g(x) \, dx =1$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for bringing up Scheffe’s lemma. Just wanna double check, based on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheffé’s_lemma), we need $\int |f_n{x}|dx\to\int|g(x)|dx$, and since $\int |f_n{x}|dx$ is always 1 (because they are density functions), as long as $\int|g(x)|dx=1$ we have Scheffe’s lemma holds, which is also true since $g(x)$ is also a density function.

Comment: That’s correct :)